# How to find things and install them with Scala sbt?

Tags: scala, junit, sbt, scalatest

I am new to Scala and struggling with sbt and installing things. For example:

I want to develop in Eclipse and hence use JUnit. According to:

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_junit_runner

"ScalaTest includes a JUnit Runner", that does not seem to be the case. At least not for me. (I get `object is not a member of package org.scalatest` when I try `import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner` but `import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec` works fine)

How do I install it? I looked at my sbt file, containing the lines:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.1" % "test"
```

and thought OK so I need org.scalatest.junit and tried to add it like:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "junit" % "3.1.1"
```

which of course gave me three(!) screens of:

```
Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scalatest:junit_2.12:3.1.1
[error]   Not found
```

(Why is it so repetitive? It's only one thing it hasn't found but it complains about it like four times!)

How do I figure out how to install things like this? Right now I am trying a combined approach of guesswork and random googling, sometimes it works and sometime (like now) it fails for me...

Answer (score 2):

In ScalaTest 3.1.x to execute ScalaTest's suites using JUnit runner add the following dependencies to `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "org.scalatest"      %% "scalatest"           % "3.1.1"     % Test,
  "org.scalatestplus"  %% "scalatestplus-junit" % "1.0.0-M2"  % Test
)
```

and annotate the suite like so

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatestplus.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class HelloSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {
  "The Hello object" should "say hello" in {
    Hello.greeting shouldEqual "hello"
  }
}
```

There exists an open issue to update the documentation: [Document how to use JUnitRunner in 3.x #1780](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1780)